# c++ initialize array with declared size as a value of an integer

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to initialize an array with a size using a value I read into an integer variable.
I cant seem to understand why it works in Dev-C++ but not in Turbo C++. Here's the code to help make things clear

```
int arr_size; //cin max value for lets say number of students or something...
cin >> arr_size;
int array[arr_size]; // declares array with size (assume 10 or 100) with range 0 to 9 or 0-99
```

The compiler shows an error in Turbo C++ (really old, I know, but my school uses it unfortunately). Dev-C++ and codeblocks doesnt.

Why is that so? I know its bad practice "as they define it in some books" to have an array size the same as an int value, but is there a work around for this in Turbo C++?
I want to know why the error happens and how I can get a work around it ... thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic array in Stack ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204521/dynamic-array-in-stack)

Comment: Always thought variable length arrays are not allowed in standard c++. You can do it in C. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not allowed in standard c++. You can do it in C99. Consider using C++ [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) as :

```
std::vector<int> array(arr_size);
```

And you can [index it](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operator%5B%5D/) exactly like the array if you have to.

Comment: Specifically, C99. Other version of C doesn't allow it either.

Answer (score 8):

The C++ standard only permits arrays to be sized with a *constant expression*.  (However, some compilers may offer it as a non-standard language extension.)

You could use a `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<int> array(arr_size);
```

Or you could dynamically-allocate memory manually:

```
int *const array = new int[arr_size];

...

delete [] array;  // Remember to delete when you're done
```

Comment: Uh, a vector *is* dynamically allocated memory?

Comment: @DeadMG: We all know he meant "or you could dynamically allocate memory *manually*".

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to dynamically allocate this array, making sure to delete the memory when done.

```
int arr_size; //cin max value for lets say number of students or something...
cin >> arr_size; 
int *arr = new int[arr_size];
//use the array as needed
delete [] arr;
```

Comment: with: delete [] arr; inside the [] what do you put?

Answer (score 1):

You want *variable* length array (VLA) which is not allowed in C++. Its allowed in C99.

Use `std::vector<int>` instead, as:

```
int arr_size; 
cin >> arr_size;
std::vector<int> array(arr_size);
```