# matrices vs. arrays of arrays in C++ and their dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, matrix, allocation

There is something I still don't quite understand about the way matrices and other multidimensional arrays are represented in C and C+ and how to allocate them dynamically.

Consider the following code segment:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n][n];
    ...
}
```

If I understand correctly, this allocates an n by n matrix of integers on the stack.
The (i,j)-th element of the matrix can be accessed using a[i][j]. The compiler
automatically converts this into an access into the (n*i+j)-th element of a one
dimensional array actually allocated.

Suppose now that I would like to allocate the n by n matrix a on the heap, instead
of the stack. I can then do the following:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int** a;
    a = new int*[n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) a[i] = new int[n];
    ...
}
```

I can now access the (i,j)-th element again as a[i][j]. However, this is not exactly 
equivalent to the situation above as I actually had to allocate space for n*n int's,
plus n pointers to int. Also, accessing a[i][j] now entails two accesses to memory instead
of just one. On the other hand, the index computation n*i+j is avoided.

Suppose now that I am interested in n by m matrices where m is small, e.g., m=2.
Using the array of row pointers then wastes 33% of the space. Is there any way of 
avoiding that?

I can of course allocate a one-dimensional array and do the index arithmetic myself,
but this does not seem to be the best solution to me.

Any information would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure your first code (with a declaration for `a[n][n]`) should work

Comment: I tested it and it does work. I also tried allocating two such n by n matrices and the difference in the addresses is 4(n*n+1). This seems to indicate that an n*n int's are indeed allocated. I am not sure why the 1 is present.

Comment: You should not care about that 1 (the compiler may force local data to be aligned).

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
 int *mat = new int[n*n];
```

then use `mat[n*i+j]`

Comment: Yes, I eluded to that possibility at the end of my post. Is there no other option?

Answer (score 1):

Rather you would allocate one linear array of ints:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int *a;
    a = new int[n*n];
}
```

Doing the index math yourself is a good way to go.

Comment: I mentioned that option at the end of my question. I am curious to know whether there is a way of avoiding doing the index math myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse the allocation order. If you are concerned about 33% or whatever memory being taken up due to "row" pointers, why not just turn the rows into the columns and vice versa? Then, instead of `[i][j]` you'd access an element with `[j][i]`. Of course, this may or may not be practical in your situation, it's hard to say without more information.

But really, I see no problems using index maths, there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

Comment: reversing the order of the indices is a good idea. It does not solve the problem completely as in a dynamic setting sometimes there are more rows and sometimes there are more columns. Also, if I want to store many 2 by 2 matrices, 33% of the space would be wasted in any case.

Comment: Of course, there is nothing morally wrong about doing the index arithmetic myself. It just seems strange that there is apparently no one of asking the compiler to do it for me.

Comment: You could always try to abstract it behind a class. I'm sure you could find an elegant way of doing this. edit: Actually, another answer already suggests this

Comment: I could definitely define a matrix class. This is suggested in one of the other answers. The question is whether this can also be down "with bare hands", so to speak. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class that did the index math for you, if that's where you're not liking things.

```
class Matrix
{
    public:
        Matrix(int iRows, int iCols)
        : mRows(iRows), mCols(iCols), m(new int[mRows*mCols]) { }
        ~Matrix() { delete [] m; }

        int &element(int iRow, int iCol) { return m[iRow * mCols + iCol]; }

        int mRows, mCols, *m;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it really necessary to define such a class. Is there no built in support for the situation I describe?

Comment: Hmmm ... I haven't really given it much thought. I'm so used to just doing the math. Is it really that inconvenient?

Comment: The best I can think of is to use a macro? #define ndx(r,c,n) (n*r+c)

Comment: Using macros is dangerous. For example, in your macro it would be much better to put n,r and c in parentheses. Doing the math is not that inconvenient. I just strikes me as odd that it is necessary.

Comment: I have always found it confusing to use two dimensional indexing because I can never remember whether it's column major or row major, especially given that it varies from language to language. Assuming the matrix to be a linear array, and doing the math just seems clearer to me. I never use multi-dimensional indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int a[n][n];
```

because the compiler needs to know exact size you will need on the stack during compile time. This is not possible when you are asking for it at run time :-) On the other hand you can do

```
#define N 10
int a[N][N];
```

In the other cases, you have to use dynamic allocation.

And allocation in C works just like that you allocate one piece of contiuous memory, indexes like a[i][j] are just syntactic sugar to jump into that memory, you can as well do *(a + k*i + j), where k is the size of the inner array.

Comment: I checked the code above using the g++ compiler and it does work! You are invited to check it yourself.

Comment: In any case. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204521/dynamic-array-in-stack

Comment: Thanks for the link! This does clarify the situation with respect to the allocation on the stack. Even though it is not standard, it seems to work with g++. As it is not standard, it is probably not such a good idea to use it.