# c++ 2 dimensional array

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

```
int main ()
{
  int line,column,i,j;
  int sortir = 1;
  float nbr;

  cout << "The number of column :";
  cin >> column;
  cout << "The number of lines: ";
  cin >> line;
  float matrice [column][line];   //creating my 2d array

  for(i=0;i <= line;i++) //asking the user to put the numbers he wants in the 2d array
    for(j=0;j <= column;j++){
      cout << "Enter a number";
      cin >> nbr;
      matrice[j][i] = nbr;
    }
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Lets say I do an array of  line = 1 and column = 1 which makes (memory zones) [0,0]  [0,1] [1,0]  [1,1]. Let's say the user inputs these following numbers:

```
[0,0]=1

[0,1]=2

[1,0]=3

[1,1]=4
```

When I want to show the user what he inputted at the end of the program: the zone [0][1] and [1][0] show the same number?

```
cout << matrice[0][0] = 1

cout << matrice[0][1] = 3 <-- why the f***

cout << matrice[1][0] = 3 <--His my for loop good?

cout << matrice[1][1] = 4
```

Comment: Avoid two dimensional arrays. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9858665/841108)

Comment: If an array has size N, you can't store N+1 elements in it.

Comment: C++ doesn't have built-in dynamically sized two dimensional arrays. If the above code compiles, you are using a compiler extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing your array out of bounds. You loop over too many elements. You need

```
for(i=0;i < line;i++) {
  for(j=0;j < column;j++){
```

Besides that, your code is not standards compliant C++, and is relying on an extension called *variable length arrays* (VLA). You cannot declare an automatic storage array with a size determined at runtime.

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
int a[i];   // ERROR (non-standard VLA extension)
const int j = 42;
int b[j];   // OK
int c[42];  // OK
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid syntax.  `float matrice[column][line]` is illegal.  You cannot have variable sized arrays in C++.  Your compiler is providing such as an extension.

Comment: You can of course create variable length arrays on the heap, using the new keyword. ```float* arr = new float[length];```

Comment: Before you do, make sure you learn the `delete` command as well.  `new` and `delete` always go hand in hand.