# Segmentation Fault when variables are not-null but on `callq`

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

**Update on Question:**
Here is the SSCCE where I receive `SIGSEV` on `str1_h[0][j] = bar1(str1_c[j]);`. All variables are not-null which I checked using gdb:

```
#include <fstream>  //ifstream and ofilestream

using namespace std;

int bar1(int);
int bar2(int);
int bar3(int);

int main() {
    string str1 = "string";
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("./file.txt");
    string line, str2;
    while (!ifs.eof()) {
        ifs >> line;
        str2 += line;
    }
    ifs.close();
    unsigned str2_l = str2.length();
    unsigned str1_l = str1.length();
    unsigned n = str2_l - str1_l + 1;   
    int str1_c[4];
    str1_c[0] = 0;
    str1_c[1] = 0;
    str1_c[2] = 0;
    str1_c[3] = 0;
    int x[3][4][n];
    int str1_h[3][4];       
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        str1_h[0][j] = bar1(str1_c[j]);
        str1_h[1][j] = bar2(str1_c[j]);
        str1_h[2][j] = bar3(str1_c[j]);
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            x[0][j][i] = bar1(0);
            x[1][j][i] = bar2(0);
            x[2][j][i] = bar3(0);
        }
    }   
}
int bar1(int x) {
    return 0;
}
int bar2(int x) {
    return 0;
}
int bar3(int x) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is your algorithm recursive? crash during a call could mean stack overflow.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Or at least show us relevant declarations and initializations, and the actual values of involved variables (like `j`).

Comment: can you step into `division` (put a breakpoint in the first line of it)

Comment: Also note that non-pointer values can't be "null", so comparing them to that is pointless.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it is not recursive

Comment: @ratchetfreak i can't i recieve SIGSEV upon entering

Comment: @JoachimPileborg please see variable declarations

Comment: _Sorry I can't provide SSCCE due to complexity of the code_ So manufacture it, in a way that it reproduces the error? You are likely to find the problem, on your own, when doing so.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius there is the SSCCE

Comment: Two things: First you should read ["Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Then you should know that C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which makes the definition of `x` technically wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [cannot have a dynamic array on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1204521/1314743) in C++:

```
int x[3][4][n];
```

either use `new`, or use an STL container (e.g. `std::vector`). See also [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936687/1314743)

Your array `x` is *on the stack*, thus writing to this array will likely overwrite important values on the stack (e.g. return pointers etc.)