# Dynamic array of pointers with template problem

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arduino

How to dynamically create an array with this class (this is Teensy Step library for arduino):

```
class StepControl : IPitHandler, IDelayHandler
{
public:
...
   StepControl();
   template<size_t N> void move(Stepper* (&motors)[N], float relSpeed = 1);
...
```

and then this is usage of this class **that works 100%** but is static:

```
 Stepper J1(0, 1), J2(2, 3), J3(4, 5), J4(6, 7), J5(8, 9), J6(10, 11);
 StepControl <> controller;

 Stepper *robot[] = {&J1,&J2,&J3,&J4,&J5,&J6};
 controller.move(robot);
```

I want to do sth like this but create array dynamically:

```
 Stepper J1(0, 1), J2(2, 3), J3(4, 5), J4(6, 7), J5(8, 9), J6(10, 11);
 StepControl <> controller;

 int j = 4
 Stepper *robot[j];
 robot[0]=&J1;
 robot[1]=&J2;
 robot[2]=&J2;
 robot[3]=&J2;
 controller.move(robot);
```

result: 
error: no matching function for call to 'StepControl<>::move(Stepper* [j])'

How to do this?

Comment: I suggest you first to figure out which language you are actually working with.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` to make your life easier.

Comment: std::vector<Stepper*> robot= {&J1,&J2,&J3,&J4}; // result error: no matching function for call to 'StepControl<>::move(std::vector<Stepper*>&)'

Comment: Note that an plain array of compile-time size `Stepper* x[N]` is _not_ the same as a mystery-sized `Stepper* x` pointer array. Try declaring `robot` as `Stepper *robot[4];`

Comment: @alterigel Ok but the size of array will change `int j=4;` is just example. If I use `Stepper *robot[4];` size will be static(4xStepper). How to use it if I would like to add 2 more dynamically but not  to use "oversized" array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your `StepControl::move()` method is written to only accept arrays whose size is known at *compile time*. This means that if the compiler can figure out the size of an array, as in:

```
// size is inferred at compile time to be 6
Stepper* robot[] = {&J1,&J2,&J3,&J4,&J5,&J6};
```

then the compiler can successfully match `controller.move(robot);` to the following template instantiation:

```
void move<>(Stepper* (&motors)[6], float relSpeed = 1);
```

But without knowing at compile time what your array size is going to be, the compiler can't match a call to `move` to a particular template instantiation. When you write

```
int j = 4;
Stepper *robot[j];
```

Because `j` is not a compile-time constant, `robot` is actually a [dynamically sized stack array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204521/dynamic-array-in-stack) which is non-standard. Some compilers allow it, but a consequence is that the size of `robot` cannot be known at compile time.

---

To fix this, you could either always be certain of your array size at compile time, as in:

```
if (needsToBeSix){
    Stepper *robots[6] = ...;
    controller.move(robots);
} else if (needsToBeFour){
    Stepper *robots[4] = ...;
    controller.move(robots);
}
```

Or, if you really need dynamically-sized arrays, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
class StepControl {
    ...
    void move(std::vector<Stepper*>& motors, float relSpeed = 1){
        // size can be queried at runtime as follows
        const size_t N = motors.size();
        // rest of method;
    }
    ...
}

...

std::vector<Stepper*> robot { &J1, &J2, &J3, &J4 };
if (needTwoMore){
    robot.push_back(&J5);
    robot.push_back(&J6);
}
controller.move(robot);
```

Comment: Thank you for very good explanation! It is very clear now. One more thing comes to my mind. If the maximum size of array is known for eg. size '10 x Stepper'. Can I declare array of known maximum size and then dynamically resize it (shrink it)? `Stepper *robots[10] = {};` then `robot[0]=&J1;...` and then `malloc` or something?

Comment: Doing that would require additional logic to track and check the size of your array. `vector` already keeps track of its own size and manages its storage automatically without you having to think about it. As an aside, you should prefer a standard container or pointer wrapper (like `vector`, `array`, `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`) to `new`, and you should _very much_ prefer `new`/`delete` to `malloc`/`free`, which won't call constructors and destructors!

Answer (score -1):

Like the idea of alter igel. Will implement the vector interface in the library so that you can use it as proposed.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out, but how does this answer Kristof's question? If you meant to add a comment, you may want to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead