# How do I get the values of an array to a vector then back to another array?

Tags: c++

[Dynamic array in Stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204521/dynamic-array-in-stack)
So from this link, I saw this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;

    std::vector<char> pz(x);
}
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
include <iostream>
include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     long int *p;
     long int *another_p;
     p = generate_random_vector(); //this is a function that generates a vector
                                   //and I'm assigning this vector to *p

     vector<long int>vectorName(n); //size n will be known when I read from a file
                                    //I would like to store the value of vector of *p in vectorName

     *another_p = vectorName; //I would like to store the value of vectorName in *another_p

     return 0;
}
```

So any suggestions on doing this?

Here's what I originally did which isn't allowed in C++:

```
int main()
{
     long int *p;
     long int *another_p;
     long int arrayName[n]; //n can be obtained from reading a file

     p = generate_random_vector(); 

     for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
     {
          arrayName[i] = p[i];
     }

     for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
     {
          another_p[i] = arrayName[i];
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, when you say "vector" you should actually *use* a vector, not pointers. Secondly, if you have two real vectors (`std::vector`) then to copy from one to the other you can use simple and plain assignment: `std::vector<long> another_vector; ...; another_vector = vectorName;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm calling it vector because mathematically it is a vector, and the code I'm trying to do is mathematics, maybe I should call it array instead?

Comment: Well do you want C++ vectors or not?

Comment: @BessieTheCow yes I do, as an alternative to the VLA.

Answer (score 2):

If you modify `generate_random_vector` to return an `std::vector<long int>`, and define `another_p` and `arrayName` as `std::vector<long int>` as well (default constructed, no need to specify size) then you can simply use assignment , as I said in my comment:

```
std::vector<long> generate_random_vector();

int main()
{
     std::vector<long> p;
     std::vector<long> another_p;
     std::vector<long> arrayName;

     p = generate_random_vector(); 

     arrayName = p;
     another_p = arrayName;
}
```

Comment: hmm, then I will have a lot to change in my code, I'll try my best!

Comment: Also, by changing all of them to vectors, I can straight do `another_p = p` right?

Comment: @Kbklpl21 Yes, plain simple assignments between vectors is possible.

Comment: Ok I tried changing everything into vectors, and it failed miserably, the code stopped at `p = generate_random_vector`. Mind looking at the code? It's long though..