# Wrong answer with user input, correct answer when input entered manually in code (KNAPSACK PROBLEM)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, dynamic-programming

I'm new to c++, just moved from python and gave a try to dynamic programming.
Ive written a piece of code for the basic "0-1 knapsack" problem, which is supposed to test my basic understanding of dynamic programming.

I think I got my algorithm right, but for some reason, when i ask the user to enter input for two of the arrays, I get a wrong answer, but when i enter  the values of these arrays within the code, I get the correct answer, everytime.

What went wrong/is wrong?

EDIT: dp is a 1001*10001 2d vector filled with -1

My solver function:

```
int knap(int n, int wt[], int price[], int W){          // n = number of items; size of array, w = wt available in knapsack
                                                        // wt stores weight if items, price:price




        if(dp[n][W] != -1){
            return dp[n][W];
        }

        else{

        // base case
        if(n == 0 || W == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(wt[n-1] <= W){           // condition for adding item to knapsack (wt of item must be less than space remaining in knapsack)

            return dp[n][W] = max((price[n-1] + knap(n-1, wt, price, W - wt[n-1])), knap(n-1, wt, price, W)) ;  // max wrt recursion from previous element
        }
        else{
            return dp[n][W] = knap(n-1, wt, price, W);
        }

}
}
```

My main function:

```
int main(){
    int n, W;
    cin>>n>>W;
    /*int b[n], b[n];
    
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        cin>>a[i];

    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++)
        cin>>b[j];
    
    */
    int a[] = { 1 ,2 ,10 ,6 ,5 ,1 ,7 ,4 ,10 ,4}, b[] = { 6, 3, 8, 1, 7, 3, 8, 6, 5, 6};
    cout<<knap(n, a, b, W);
}
```

the answer is supposed to be 21, which i get when a[] and b[] have been defined, but when I make the user input a[] and b[] (as written in the commented region of the code) value, I get the wrong answer.

example input test cases with their outputs:

```
Input:
10 10
1 2 10 6 5 1 7 4 10 4
6 3 8 1 7 3 8 6 5 6
output:
21

Input:
4 10
4 8 5 3
5 12 8 1

Output:
13
```

Comment: "but for some reason, when i ask the user to enter input for two of the arrays, I get a wrong answer, but when i enter the values of these arrays within the code, I get the correct answer, everytime." In the version where you tried asking the user to enter input, did you try checking *that the input values are what you expect*?

Comment: Are you expecting `int b[n]` to work in C++ with a user-input value? Why/how? Are you familiar with `std::vector`? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204521/dynamic-array-in-stack .

Comment: I did. w\When trying to solve this earlier, i had the code print out a[] and b[] after user input, so that i know its being input correctly.

Comment: it is @The_Redhawk

Comment: I tried your (fixed) sample of yesterday with input values. In my case, the results are identical: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/011139351f4e3e91)